# jquery form submit not work by clicking a link

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form which input type is hidden. I want to submit it by clicking a link what is outside the form.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="phpfile.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="somevalue" />
</form>

<a id="link" href="">link</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').click(function(){
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

but when i submit the form by a submit button it works fine.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, do you have any error message? What's the behavior exactly when you click on the link?

Comment: yeah, what's happend after click on a tag ?

Comment: You can avoid using jQuery if the submit link is an input (or button). Does it have to be an anchor link and not something like this: <input id="link" type="submit" /> ?

Comment: By using div it works, but i need to do this through a link.

Comment: When i click on the link, nothing happen, no error message too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code using another element

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" method="post" action="phpfile.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="somevalue" /><input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<div id="link" href="">link</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').on('click',function(){
    alert('a');
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of an anchor, just use a div. Clicking on an anchor will "eat" the event, so either you prevent the bubbling or simply use another element, like a div.

Comment: By using div it works! but i need to do this through a link.

Comment: and i can not prevent default too

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code using anchor as triggering element.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" method="post" action="phpfile.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="somevalue" /><input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<a id="link" href="">link</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#link').on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        $('#form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need to do this without preventing default.

Comment: then you must use another element, not an <a>